# toggling the movement of content from one div to another

Tags: jquery

Searched everywhere but cannot find an answer to this problem. When I click on a button I want content to move from one div to another and then when clicked again to move back. Can make the initial move no problem but it's the getting back.

Here's my code so far...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){$('#button').click(function() {
       $(this).val() == "Move Content" ? initial_move() : move_back();
        });
    });

    function initial_move() {
        $('#button').val("Move Back");
        $("#two").append($("#toggle_txt").html());  
        $('div#one #toggle_txt').remove();
    };

    function move_back() {
        $('#button').val("Move Content");
        $("#one").append($("#toggle_txt").html());  
        $('div#two #toggle_txt').remove();
    };
});


<input type="button" value="Move Content" id="button" /><br/><br/>

<div id="one">
    <p>Div One permanent text</p>
    <p id="toggle_txt">Text to toggle between the two</p>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="two">
    <p>Div Two permanent text</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eBuAz/

I don't see why this code shouldn't work. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
$('div#one #toggle_txt').remove();
```

you are actually removing this from the DOM, so there is no text to be added back to.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) 
{
    $(function(){$('#button').click(function()
    {
        $(this).val() == "Move Content" ? initial_move() : move_back();
    });
    });

    function initial_move() {
        $('#button').val("Move Back");
        var toggle = $("#toggle_txt");
        $("#two").append(toggle).html();
        $('div#one #toggle_txt').remove();
        toggle.attr('id', "toggle_txt");
    };

    function move_back() {
        $('#button').val("Move Content");
        var toggle = $("#toggle_txt");
        $("#one").append(toggle).html();  
        $('div#two #toggle_txt').remove();
        toggle.attr('id', "toggle_txt");
    };
});
```

Comment: That's great @Samurai thanks so much. I'm studying your answer trying to get my head around the logic. In initial_move() we remove #toggle_txt from div#one but then aren't we applying an id of toggle_txt to an element that already has it? It works great so I can use it but just nice to get the logic in my head. I really appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Thanks @defau1t I'm quite a novice at jquery so I can see what you're saying and it makes sense. Samurai has come up with a solution. I noticed in the source code that the position of the div doesn't change but it is visually moved. Appreciate your comment.

Comment: What you do is you add content of element one to element two then your remove the element with id toggle_txt. So when you click again (on move back) there is actually no element with toggle_txt id. What I added is I store the element in a variable and then set its id to toggle_txt after the previous element with that id was removed.

Comment: I see now @Samurai that is brilliant, simple when you know how! Can't thank you enough for your time and knowledge.